# Mobius inversion problem

Tags: number-theory, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

Prove by Mobius inversion formula if $\frac{n}{\phi(n)}=\sum_{d\mid n} f(d)$ then $f(d)=\frac{\mu^2(d)}{\phi(d)}.$

Comment: Your question would benefit from having a bit more context. Such as Source? Your thoughts/partial progress? Surrounding theory and examples? Possibly also from other points listed in [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume here that $f$ is multiplicative.  By Möbius inversion, $$f(n)= \sum_{d \mid n} \frac{n\mu(d)}{d\phi(n/d)}.$$  Since both sides are multiplicative, it is enough to compute $f$ on prime powers.  If $r \geq 2$, we find $$f(p^r) = \frac{p^r}{\phi(p^r)} - \frac{p^{r-1}}{\phi(p^{r-1})}  =\frac{p^r-p^r}{\phi(p^r)}=0= \frac{\mu^2(p^r)}{\phi(p^r)},$$ while if $r=1$, we find $$f(p) = \frac{p}{p-1} - 1 = \frac{1}{p-1} = \frac{\mu^2(p)}{\phi(p)}.$$

Extending by multiplicativity, we get that $$f(d)= \frac{\mu^2(d)}{\phi(d)}.$$